# display logged in user firstname and last name instead of email in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to get logged in user first name and last name. The problem is: I can easily get the user email from user table because it is in user table.
But the first and last name is from other table which is contacts table.

Here I want to get user first and last name from contacts table which is separated from user table any help would be highly appreciated?

My code code snippet is

```
  @if(Auth::check())
      <li><a href="{{ url('/admin') }}" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:8px;">Hi {{Auth::user()->email}}</a></li>
  @else
      <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:8px;">Login</a></li>
  @endif`
```

Comment: Just use 'one-to-one' or 'one - to - many' relationships.

Comment: Change `{{Auth::user()->email}}` blade binding for `{{Auth::user()-> whatever_field_you_want}}`

Comment: Do you have a Model for your contacts table?

Comment: yes i have a model for conatcts

Comment: i am still stuck in this issue /: can i done this by making relationship is user and contact model ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a `column` named `user_id` in `contacts` table.

In `User` model:

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contact', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

In `Contact` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then replace this:

```
{{Auth::user()->email }}
```

With this:

```
{{ Auth::user()->contact ? Auth::user()->contact->first_name.' '.Auth::user()->contact->last_name : '' }}
```

This should work.

Comment: i tried this but it showing error unknown coloumn contacts.user_id even i dont have any user_id column in contacts table. My relationship is as it is as you said me and my code is now

Comment: can anybody tell me whats problem is it i am facing ??

Comment: @shahzadhussain, check my modified answer. By the way are you using `database migration` ?

Comment: Thanks it working fine now but i used the other way i created function in which i directly make join of users table with contacts and call this function to my code view ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the foreign key for `users` in `contacts` table is named `user_id`.

In `User` model:

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contact', 'user_id');
}
```

If you have a different name for the foreign key, then substitute that in place of `user_id`.

Rest all as @Md Mahfuzur Rahman has suggested.

Comment: @shahzad hussain If you don't have a foreign key for `users` in `contacts` table, then you should add a column for that; else your relationships won't work.

Comment: i added user_id column in my contacts table its shwoing fine but i cannot show my first and last name this is i want

Comment: i done same thing as @md mahfuzur rehman said but nothing is happening

Comment: My User  model is   public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\contacts','user_id');
    }

Comment: contact model is  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

Comment: and my code is Hi{{ Auth::user()->contact ? Auth::user()->contact->firstname.' '.Auth::user()->contact->lastname: ''}}    This is only showing output Hi i want to display first and last name with Hi

Comment: In your User model it should be capital **C** for Contacts. Also, is it Contacts or Contact?

Comment: it is model name with small s that is contacts

Comment: Please edit your question and give complete code for models User and Contact, and table schema for users and contacts.

Comment: My question is i want to display full name of logged in like Hi Shahzad hussain and with first and last name and my first and last name is in contacts table not in user table

Comment: and i make a relationship in user model which is  public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\contacts');
    }

Comment: and relationship in contacts model which is     public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

Comment: and my whole code in which i am working is   Hi{{ Auth::user()->contact ? Auth::user()->contact->firstname.' '.Auth::user()->contact->lastname: ''}}

Comment: thats all with my question

Comment: I've read your question and understood it perfectly. Now if you need help, then please provide the aforementioned details.

Comment: public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contact');
}
In Contact model:

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
Then replace this:

{{Auth::user()->email }}
With this:

{{ Auth::user()->contact ? Auth::user()->contact->first_name.' '.Auth::user()->contact->lastname. ' ' }}

Comment: thats thing the brother earlier refer me and i done same thing like he said

Comment: I notice you're using `App\Contact` and not `App\contacts`. Now would you mind adding the second parameter as I suggested in my answer? `public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contact', 'user_id');
}`